# Multiple Times load of image from API in ImageView in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made a custom Tableview which has an image view and some labels that takes values from API.

It's a custom table in which images and labels recieve data from API related to real estate .

When my custom table loads, values start coming from API.

The actual issue ocurr in image view . I have set a local image in an image view , when the data coming from API has no image than it should show local image otherwise data should show its original image submitted by customer in the forms.

Now when data start coming from API first in image view it shows local image than when images start coming from API it start showing that but when we scroll down in image view it shows same images in image view and repeats many times and we cannot identify that which is original image.

I can provide the code if anyone sent me his email , he can get all the senario of work.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    StringData* cust = [_Title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.Title.text = cust.title1;
    cell.area.text=cust.Area;
    cell.city.text=cust.City;
    cell.phone.text=cust.phoneno;
    cell.price.text=cust.Price;
    cell.location1.text=cust.location;
    cell.name1.text=cust.dealer_name;
    cell.email1.text=cust.dealer_email;
    cell.type1.text=cust.property_type;
    cell.status1.text=cust.status;
    cell.room1.text=cust.rooms;
    cell.washrooms.text=cust.bath;
    cell.floor1.text=cust.floors;
    cell.imagetext.text = cust.images;

    tii=cell.Title.text;
    NSLog(@"Tittttttle is %@",tii);


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cust.images];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data,    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (data) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (image) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.images1.image = image;
                });
            }
        }
    }];
    [task resume];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include relevant code. In particular your `cellForRow(at:)` method. Your are almost certainly not accounting for cell reuse as your table scrolls; there are countless similar questions on this site about that

Comment: Fetching the image each time is not very efficient. You should use some sort of caching, such as SDWebImage.   Also you are not setting a placeholder image before the download starts, so the image view will contain whatever image was put into it last. In your closure you might also want to check that the indexpath for the cell is the indexpath your just downloaded an image for since the table could have scrolled and the cell be reused since you started the download.

Comment: can u please explain if i send u my project using mail. @Paulw11

Comment: This issue occurred because  reusable cell .
When you down scroll 1st cell is reuse instead of last cell . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196096/uitableview-reusable-cell-issue-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you don't store an image into local application memory. You tried to load image on every time when cell is appear. So you download image every time.

Best Solution:

You need to store image local memory using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Objective-C:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
...
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"IMAGE_URL"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Swift:

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "IMAGE_URL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

If you are loading an image for the first time, then it will download and store an image into local memory. So from second times, it will load from local itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Nirmalsinh

Answer (score 0):

Well, its because your cell is getting re-used and the previous image is being displayed. You can override [prepareForReuse()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method of your tableviewcell subclass or consider setting placeholder for the url image using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

**Edit: Explaination**

You are downloading your image asyc and setting it to your imageview of your tableviewcell, what is happening here is while your next image is being downloaded, before that your cell is re-used and displays previous image.